# fullcalendar.js 24 hour calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How do I change from am/pm to 24 hour time format?

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/ That wasn't so hard to find?

Comment: I had the same problem, the solution is not obvious

Comment: You need only these two: `timeFormat: 'H:mm', axisFormat: 'H:mm'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change h(:mm)tt and /h:mm{ - h:mm} to H in fullcalendar.js

```
setDefaults({
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayText: 'all-day',
    firstHour: 6,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    defaultEventMinutes: 120,
    axisFormat: 'H', //,'h(:mm)tt',
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'H' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
    },
    dragOpacity: {
        agenda: .5
    },
    minTime: 0,
    maxTime: 24
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize the `timeFormat` property on the calendar object.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

Comment: Don't forget to set the `axisFormat` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
timeFormat: {
   agenda: 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm}'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        //pull from my database the events
    }
    // other events here...
],
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
});
```

Comment: For the v3 version, use `slotLabelFormat: 'H(:mm)',`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set axisFormat. See the following code:

```
<p:schedule value="#{scheduleView.lazyEventModel}" timeFormat="HH:mm" axisFormat="HH:mm"/>
```

It displays in 24h format